# I cannot move my GTAV save from my old PS3 to my new PS3

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-v

I had to purchase a new PS3 after my old one died. I had all my game saves backed up on a USB stick, but now GTA-V won't let me access them on my new console. It just comes up with an error saying you didn't create this so you cant use it. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you transferred that data to the new PS3 yet? Or is it still on your USB drive?

Comment: Did you recreate the old account on the new PS3, or make a new one?  I *have* copied game saves from one PS3 to another before now, but maybe they've put something in to lock it to the account.

Comment: You could try removing the hard drive from the old console and putting it in the new one.

Comment: @Ric If you do that it detects it's not the hard drive for that device and says it needs to format it before use.

Comment: @Ric No, don't ever do that.  Each hard drive is encrypted to its own PS3.  Swapping hard drives will just make you lose the data on it, not move it to another console.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Sign into your PSN account and then try copying the save file.The saves will work only in the same account that it was created, which is the PSN account that your old PS3 uses.